# How to avoid the dropdown from disappearing when removing cursor from the button?

Tags: html, css

When I hover over the button I see the dropdown menu however, when I navigate to any of the item on the menu the dropdown menu just disappears. I think I know the problem is that I have hover added on the button only, but how can I make it work like a normal dropdown ?

```css
.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  /* background:#f1f1f1; */
}

.dropbtn {
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  list-style: none;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
}

.dropdown-content li {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  padding: 3px;
}

.dropdown-content li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 3px;
}

.dropdown-content li:hover,
.dropdown-content li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  background-color: #333;
}

.dropbtn:hover+.dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">More</button>
  <ul class="dropdown-content">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I want the dropdown menu to stay visible while I am hovering over the child elements in the dropdown menu as any other dropdown menu works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set the `:hover` property directly on the `.dropdown` element like this :

```css
.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  /*background:#f1f1f1; */
}

.dropbtn {
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  list-style: none;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
}

.dropdown-content li {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  padding: 3px;
}

.dropdown-content li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 3px;
}

.dropdown-content li:hover,
.dropdown-content li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  background-color: #333;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">More</button>
  <ul class="dropdown-content">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks man this works, how silly I was focusing on button and not the entire div element itself.

Comment: @craigbob44 glad I could help. Please accept this answer (click on the tick on the left of this answer) as it solves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `hover` in CSS, which is the normal behaviour for your case. If you want to click on the button, and display the dropdown you will need some Javascript and an onclick event :

```js
function showDropdown() {
  var content = document.getElementById("dropdown-content");
  if (content.style.display === "block") {
    content.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    content.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```css
.dropdown{
  display:inline-block;
  padding:5px;
/*   background:#f1f1f1; */
}

.dropbtn{
  padding:5px;
  margin-bottom:0px;
  width:100%;
}

.dropdown-content{
  display:none;
  list-style:none;
  background:#f1f1f1;
  position:relative;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  margin:0px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index:1;
  width:100%;
}

.dropdown-content li{
  margin-bottom:0px;
  padding:3px;
}

.dropdown-content li a{
  text-decoration:none;
  color:black;
  padding:3px;
}

.dropdown-content li:hover
,.dropdown-content li a:hover{
  text-decoration:none;
  color:white;
  background-color:#333;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn" onclick="showDropdown()">More</button>
  <ul class="dropdown-content" id="dropdown-content">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Well I wanted to use hover for dropdown menu and my problem has been solved by other user however I also wanted to code a navbar menu too that requires a click and your solution is perfect for that. Thanks a lot mate :)